# Update an array in the state of function component

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, state

I developed an application that allows the user to upload images from the device, then I save the uploaded images in an array called LocalImages as the following:

```
const _pickImage = async () => {
      let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      })
    let imageUri = pickerResult
       imageUri && {uri: imageUri} 
// here is the array where i save all images.
       setLocalImage(LocalImage.concat([{ 
       uri: pickerResult.uri,
       width: 700,
       height: 450 }]));
         ;
    }
```

After that, I display the images using .map for the user and if the user press on an image he/she can edit that image then I re-save the new image URI.
The problem is:
I couldn't find a way to update the state and replace the old URI with the new one. Here is the current code: it only adds the edited image to the array.

```
 setLocalImage(
           LocalImage.concat([{
           uri : imageUri, width: 700, height: 40
          }]))
```

I used the splice method but it results in deleting other images.
Here is the console log shows what's inside LocalImage:
[LocalImage array log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUojJ.png)

The question is: Is there a way to replace the old URI and update the state with the new one?

Comment: in map function you can access an index of each element `Array.map((data, index) => {})` by using index you can replace the old URI

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't know the correct syntax could you tell me? @RagulCs

Comment: Read more, about [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I read it, but the problem is updating the state array, not in understanding maps. @Nur

Comment: In react, you have to update state by replacing it, To solve your problem you need an unique id for image,
`setLocalImage(images => images.map(img => img.id == id ? { id, url, width, height } : img));`